# Invalid subset type list

Tags: list, subset, logistic-regression

Hello I am tryieng the below code with the error "Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list variables_relevantes is data.frame':

train2 is data.frame' 580 obs. of  25 variables

variables_relevantes  is  'data.frame':580 obs. of  21 variables

train3 is data.frame' 580 obs. of  21 variables

RISK2" is a column present in all the dataframe ".  Thanks really`

```
variables_relevantes <- train2 %>% select_if(is.numeric)

aux <- train3[,c("RISK2",variables_relevantes)]

# Fits a full logistic regression model
full.model <- glm(formula = RISK2 ~ ., 
                  data = aux, 
                  family = binomial())

# Perform stepwise logistic regression using AIC as the criterion.
step.model <- stepAIC(full.model, 
                      direction = "both", 
                      trace = FALSE) # use "forward", "backward" or "both" for address

# Shows the summary of the final model
summary(step.model)
```